# Android app crashing on call of a method. The method runs some if statements and changes the drawables on some imageviews

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I am creating a class to use in an android app. It should keep track of a grid of "tiles", which can change colors. but it keeps crashing when the "checkTile" method that I created is called. That method simply runs through some if statements to see if any of the surrounding tiles are "blank", then calls the "switchTile" command on any blank tiles, which swaps the drawables of two imageviews.

The logcat says:
3474-3474/? E/VCD: init_modem : Fail to open /dev/umts_atc0, errno = 2

Here is the class:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class TileBoard {
    private Drawable[][] tiles;
    private Drawable blank;

    public TileBoard(int width, int height, Drawable blank) {
        tiles = new Drawable[width][height];
        this.blank = blank;
    }

    public void switchTiles(int tile1X, int tile1Y, int tile2X, int tile2Y) {
        Drawable placeholder = tiles[tile1X][tile1Y];
        tiles[tile1X][tile1Y] = tiles[tile2X][tile2Y];
        tiles[tile2X][tile2Y] = placeholder;
    }

    public void checkTile(int tileX, int tileY) {
        if (tileX != 0) if (tiles[tileX - 1][tileY].equals(blank))
            switchTiles(tileX, tileY, tileX - 1, tileY);
        if (tileY != 0) if (tiles[tileX][tileY - 1].equals(blank))
            switchTiles(tileX, tileY, tileX, tileY - 1);
        if (tileX != tiles[0].length) if (tiles[tileX + 1][tileY].equals(blank))
            switchTiles(tileX, tileY, tileX + 1, tileY);
        if (tileY != tiles.length) if (tiles[tileX][tileY + 1].equals(blank))
            switchTiles(tileX, tileY, tileX, tileY + 1);
    }

    public void scrambleBoard() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles.length; j++) {
                int randomPositionX = rand.nextInt(tiles[0].length);
                int randomPositionY = rand.nextInt(tiles.length);
                switchTiles(i, j, randomPositionX, randomPositionY);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setBoard(ArrayList<Drawable> images) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length * 5; i += 5) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles[0].length; j++) {
                tiles[j][i / 5] = images.get(i + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Logcat report of the crash?

Comment: It's probably `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: It's really easy to identify an error by looking at logcat.

Comment: I added the part of the logcat that appeared in red

Comment: Thank you @Md.Asaduzzaman. It was an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, Now the method simply doesn't do anything. An improvement, but the app still doesn't work.

Comment: Add logging in as much detail as you need to track down the problem, and/or step through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. There were two things wrong. First of all, in some of the if statements in checkTile needed to have the condition `tileY != tiles.length - 1` instead of `tileY != tiles.length`. The lack of the -1 was causing a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Second, I was trying to compare drawables with the `.equals` command, which apparently doesn't work on drawables.

Thank you to @Md. Asaduzzaman, who pointed out the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`